# How we could display video's screenshots from external storage in listview?

Tags: android, cursor, simplecursoradapter, universal-image-loader

I use universal imageloader to display images  from external storage in listview
,while i need to show videos (their screenshots) in listview as well.
How could it be implemented via universal image loader or via using other libs?
as without using such loaders I have issues of outofmemoryexception,that is 
why i do prefer to use such loaders

Answer (score 0):

private void generatePicturethumbnail(){

```
 File picfile = new File(util.getPicturePath());
 FileOutputStream fos = null;
try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream(picfile);
    Bitmap map = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(util.getVideoFilePath(), Thumbnails.FULL_SCREEN_KIND);
     if(map!=null){
     map.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
     }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks,I know this solution,but i don't know how it use it in universalimageloader
as i am passing url to imageLoader.displayImage()

how  do i need to override in classes of universalimageloader to display videos?